# Module missing when uninstalling

Tags: 8, composer

When I try to uninstall a module using composer I get an error about the same module is missing, but the module exists. For example, if I run this command:

```
composer remove drupal/bamboo_twig
```

I get:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 1 removal
  - Removing drupal/bamboo_twig (4.1.0)
Deleting web/modules/contrib/bamboo_twig - deleted
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
30 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

In PmCommands.php line 259:

  Unable to install modules bamboo_twig due to missing modules bamboo_twig.


pm:enable [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-d|--debug] [-y|--yes] [--no] [--remote-host REMOTE-HOST] [--remote-user REMOTE-USER] [-r|--root ROOT] [-l|--uri URI] [--simulate] [--pipe] [-D|--define DEFINE] [--druplicon] [--notify [NOTIFY]] [--xh-link XH-LINK] [--] <command> [<modules>]...
```

The module was installed previously.
I don't understand this weird warning.
I have tried with another module, and I have got the same issue.

Comment: First uninstall the module (Drush or Drupal UI) and only then remove it (Composer remove). For this to happen during automated deployments you may need two consecutive releases. First release uninstalls the module. Second release removes it.

Comment: No. It doesn't work. That's the way I do it usually, but I get the same error. I uninstall the module with success, but after this, when I run composer remove, I get the same error.

Comment: Uninstall, config export, release wait 'til done. Composer remove, release, wait 'til done. If you don't push the updated config in the first step, the module will never be uninstalled on Prod. Which leads to the error you get after you removed it with Composer without uninstalling it first.

Comment: Uninstall (from Drupal UI), Manage > Configuration > Development > Configuration Synchronization > Export all, wait until done (tar.gz file downloaded). Go to ssh, composer remove drupal/bamboo_twig ... same error.

Comment: And you can confirm the module is definitely uninstalled before you composer remove it? And that it isn't a dependency of a theme for example?

Comment: The module is definitely uninstalled but I causes troubles in the future when you want to install a new module, and breaks drush too.

Comment: What? Can you maybe update your question and provide all necessary steps to reproduce this issue with a fresh Drupal installation?

Comment: I'm not sure because it only happens on one installation. I get the same error even when I install a new module. If I run composer require drupal/other_module, the other_module is downloaded to contrib folder, but I get the same error, that is, the module is missing. After this if I run drush en:module other_module, the module is installed ok. It's very weird.